# create a database table containing students information like serial number, registration number, name, age, subject marks ,average ,cgpa and branch

Tags: mysql

I have written this code:

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT_INFORMATION(
    SL_NO INT NOT NULL ,
    REGISTRATION_ID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    AGE INT NOT NULL,
    CSE2001 INT NOT NULL,
    CSE2008 INT NOT NULL,
    CSE3002 INT NOT NULL,
    AVERAGE FLOAT NOT NULL,
    CGPA FLOAT NOT NULL,
    BRANCH VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (REGISTRATION_ID)
);
INSERT INTO student_information VALUES(1,'21BCE9261','Abhiram Rayidi',18,92,93,94,93,8.6,'Cse Ai&Ml');
INSERT INTO student_information VALUES(2,'21BCE9150','Kowshik Velaga',18,95,96,97,96,9.2,'Cse Ai&Ml');
INSERT INTO student_information VALUES(3,'21BCE7019','SomaSekhar Kilaru',18,94,96,98,96,8.9,'Cse Ai&Ml');
INSERT INTO student_information VALUES(4,'21BCE8450','Manoj Desu',19,90,93,95,93,8.8,'Cse Ai&Ml');
INSERT INTO student_information VALUES(5,'21BCE7773','Vardhan Chilukuri',20,92,93,94,93,8.1,'Cse Ai&Ml');
INSERT INTO student_information VALUES(6,'21BCE8942','Prakash Padarthy',19,92.5,94.5,96.5,94.5,8.4,'Cse DA');
INSERT INTO student_information VALUES(7,'21BCE8677','Sathwik Yanaganti',19,91,92,95,92.67,8.7,'Cse BT');
INSERT INTO student_information VALUES(8,'21BCE7389','Jaswanth Jangala',18,98,98,98,98,9.6,'Cse Ai&Ml');
INSERT INTO student_information VALUES(9,'21BCE7554','Aditya Vardhan',19,90,91,92,91,8,'Cse Core');
INSERT INTO student_information VALUES(10,'21BCE7859','SaiSiva Krishna',20,90,93,94,92.33,8.3,'Cse Ai&Ml');
SELECT * FROM STUDENT_INFORMATION;
```

Output:

[image]

I want to get the serial number in order without giving changing the primary key from registration id. Is it possible to do so? Also can the average be calculated when the marks are given me?

Comment: 'can the average be calculated when the marks are given me' - average of what?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to have an ascending order

```
SELECT * FROM STUDENT_INFORMATION ORDER BY SL_NO ASC;
```

Or this for descending order

```
SELECT * FROM STUDENT_INFORMATION ORDER BY SL_NO DESC;
```